# System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed. pointing to a line in an XML File

Tags: xml, registry, boolean, deserialization

My code has a problem deserializing from an xml file.  The property in my entity class returns a Boolean value, which may accept "Y" or "N" and True/False.  Other properties as string are read smoothly except for it.  Upon enclosing my code in a Try-Catch block, I was able to find out the line of code which returns an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, a bit confusing to name this error as a security exception.  What I did on my xml file, is to change the value from True to 1 and False to 0.